# How to extract time from string?

Tags: r

A set of files have been named according to their time duration. For example, "832-34" means 08:32 AM to 08:34 AM. The hyphen is used in all the file names, how do I extract the time from them?

Comment: Please add 5-10 example and show expected output for it. It is difficult to generalise based on only one example.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the only one existing example above. There is no guarantee for working under other constellations.

```
t <- "832-34"

t_from <- sub("-.*", "", t)
t_from <- gsub('^(.{-3})(.*)$', '\\1:\\2', t_from)
t_from <- as.POSIXct(t_from,format="%H:%M")

t_to <- sub(".*-", "", t)
t_to <- paste0(hour(t_from), ":",t_to)
t_to <-  as.POSIXct(t_to,format="%H:%M")

paste(format(t_from, '%H:%M'), "to", format(t_to, '%H:%M'))
```